# Windres errors in .rc file

Tags: c++, command-line, mingw

When I try to use windres (Included with MinGW) to compile my .rc file using the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable), it gives me the following error (I put "windres my.rc -O coff -o my.res" into the command line):

```
cpp: Too many arguments
windres: my.rc:1: syntax error
```

my.rc is as follows:

```
1 ICON "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\LonelyPlanet\LonelyPlanetIcon.ico"
2 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION  1,0,0,0
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "040904E4"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "CompanyName", "Neil Flodin"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "A game I made at iD tech camp!"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "Lonely_Planet"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright(c) Neil Flodin All Rights Reserved"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Lonely Planet.exe"
      VALUE "ProductName", "Lonely Planet"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0"
    END
  END

  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
  END
END
```

Is there anything weird that I'm doing with my rc file/command line input, and if so, how could I make windres compile it?

-Neil

Comment: Could you try changing the path name to use forward slashes `/` rather than backslashes `\\`?

Comment: It still gives me the same error for some reason...

Comment: The problem is with the long path name I believe, try moving the icon to directly under the C drive and make the path `C:/LonelyPlanetIcon.ico`, (always forward slashes!) or put the file together with the .res file and just type "LonelyPlanetIcon.ico" it should work.

Comment: Still same error... :( I have no idea why, though. I even ditched the ICON line and it gets the same error

Comment: Last guess, try `windres my.rc -o my.res` without specifying the file format (I tried your file here, and I successfully compiled it).

Comment: Sadly, the same thing... I'm going to reinstall windres at this point.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <winresrc.h>
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "main.ico"
VERSIONINFO
...
END
```

add resource.h

```
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provide a possible solution to a similar problem ([Windres syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497838/windres-syntax-error/36665553#36665553)) posted 4 years ago from today.

I hope it can helps. The point is that you can try to compile the `.rc` file in the same way, but using **Cygwin**, and obtaing a `.o` file instead a `.res` one, that you can use in the linking process.